# How to use forEach to set multiple properties while returning destructured output in setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Here is the original code

```
setRows((rows) =>
  rows.map((row) =>
    selected && row.node === selected.id
      ? { ...row, row.a: "", 
                  row.b: "", 
                  row.c: "" }
      : row
  )
);
```

I would have multiple properties inside row e.g., a, b, c, and so on. I have a constant named **PosisbleValues** containing name of those properties but how can i use it to iterate over while setting new values of row?

Currently, I'm using the following approach which is directly changing the state.

```
setRows((rows) => {
  const row = rows.find(
    (row) => selected && row.node === selected.id
  );
  if (row) {
    PossibleValues.forEach(
      (val) => (row[val] = "")
    );
  }
  return rows;
});
```

Why do I want to do this? Because these properties a, b, c will increase/change in the future and I just want to change that in one file (i.e, where my PossibleValues const string array is residing).

Comment: What is the `PosisbleValues`? Please show it

Comment: @kinduser const PossibleValues = ["a", "b", "c"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your first example like this:

```
setRows((rows) =>
  rows.map((row) =>
    selected && row.node === selected.id
      ? { ...row, ...{a: "", b: "", c: ""}}
      : row
  )
);
```

But `{a: "", b: "", c: ""}` can be computed from the contents of `PossibleValues` using `Object.fromEntries(PossibleValues.map(key => ([key, ""]))`.

So the final code would be:

```
setRows((rows) =>
  rows.map((row) =>
    selected && row.node === selected.id
      ? { ...row, ...(Object.fromEntries(PossibleValues.map(key => ([key, ""])))}
      : row
  )
);
```